# Sharepoint 2013 How to hide Gear Button for non admins without change masterpage

Tags: site-settings, hide-elements, sharepoint-standard

I would like to hide the gear button for non admins users of my SharePoint website. And to perform, I don't want to modify code from my masterPage (i am not allowed to do this). But I can create a copy of it, a kind of Custom MasterPage but I do not know what code to put on it to hide the gear button ONLY for non admin user.
I was thinking about permission level but i do not know which on to put on (or off) to avoid users (even contributor user) to get this gear button.
Thanks for your precious help!

Comment: you can't unless you add a css on every site page, wikipage and listview page some CSS to hide the Site Actions button

Answer (score 2):

Finally I get it!!

**Step 1:** I have duplicated my masterpage in a custom masterpage.
To do so :

Gear button/site setting/Web Designer Galleries Part/Master Pages

- find the master page by default (mine was seattle.master)
- click on the narrow and choose :Download a copy
- on my PC I renamed it as custom_seattle.master" and uploaded it in the same gallery.
- on the metadata when uploaded, put in Type content : ASP NET MasterPage

**Step 2:** In SharePoint Designer, in Master Page list, find your custom_seatle.master page, click check out and advanced modify.
In the page code, find : MenuItemTemplate (it is about 8 occurrences)
and in the attributes, find PermissionsString and replace value(s) by "FullMask" and find PermissionMode and replace value by "All"
example :

```
<SharePoint:MenuItemTemplate runat="server" ID="MenuItem_ViewAllSiteContents"
    Text="<%$Resources:wss,quiklnch_allcontent_15%>"
    Description="<%$Resources:wss,siteactions_allcontentdescription%>"
    ImageUrl="/_layouts/15/images/allcontent32.png?rev=23"
    MenuGroupId="200"
    Sequence="240"
    UseShortId="true"
    ClientOnClickNavigateUrl="~siteLayouts/viewlsts.aspx"
    PermissionsString="FullMask"
    PermissionMode="All" />
```

Save your page, check in by put publish principal version.

**Step 3:** in your SharePoint Site in browser, go to this page: `/_layouts/15/changesitemasterpage.aspx` (example : http://mySpWebSite/_layouts/15/changesitemasterpage.aspx)
And in the properties list, choose your custom page (custom_seatle.master)

And it is OK!!! :)

Comment: How can we hide the gear icon in HTML Master page? It seems MenuItem is not existing in HTML master page.

Answer (score 1):

Are you allowed to add *Custom Actions*?

if so then you could use this code here:

```
(function getCustomAction() {
    this.clientContext = new SP.ClientContext();
    var oWebsite = clientContext.get_web();
    this.collUserCustomAction = oWebsite.get_userCustomActions();
    clientContext.load(oWebsite, 'UserCustomActions', 'Title');
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.enumerateCustomActions), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
})()

function enumerateCustomActions() {
    var customActionEnumerator = collUserCustomAction.getEnumerator();
    var exists = false;
    while (customActionEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var oUserCustomAction = customActionEnumerator.get_current();
        if (oUserCustomAction.get_title() == 'HideGearIcon') {
            exists = true;
            oUserCustomAction.deleteObject();
            clientContext.load(oUserCustomAction);
            clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onDeleteQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!exists) {
        oUserCustomAction = collUserCustomAction.add();
        oUserCustomAction.set_location('ScriptLink');
        oUserCustomAction.set_sequence('1000');
        oUserCustomAction.set_title('HideGearIcon');
        oUserCustomAction.set_scriptBlock(`\
            document.write(\'\
                \\<script\\>\
                    SP.SOD.executeFunc("sp.js", "SP.ClientContext", checkPermissions);\
                    function checkPermissions (){\
                        var ctx = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();\
                        var web = ctx.get_web();\
                        var ob = new SP.BasePermissions();\
                        ob.set(SP.PermissionKind.manageWeb);\
                        var perm = web.doesUserHavePermissions(ob);\
                        ctx.executeQueryAsync(\
                            function () {\
                                if(!perm.get_value()){\
                                    addCSS("#O365_MainLink_Settings {display:none !important}");\
                                }\
                            }, function (a, b) {\
                                addCSS("#O365_MainLink_Settings {display:none !important}");\
                            }\
                        );\
                    };\
                    function addCSS(css){\
                        var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];\
                        var s = document.createElement("style");\
                        s.setAttribute("type", "text/css");\
                        if (s.styleSheet) {\
                            s.styleSheet.cssText = css;\
                        } else {\
                            s.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css));\
                        };\
                        head.appendChild(s);\
                    }\
                \\</script\\>\
            \');\
        `);
        oUserCustomAction.update();
        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onDeployQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
    }
}

function onDeleteQuerySucceeded() {
    alert('CustomAction removed');
}

function onDeployQuerySucceeded() {
    alert('CustomAction deployed');
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    alert('Something went wrong: ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

This code will deploy a *Custom Action* which checks the users permission and injects some CSS into the page if the user does not have the *ManageWeb* permission. The code that actually deploys the *Custom Action* is wrapped in another function that allows you to toggle the *Custom Action* on and off. Execute this code in the console of your browser and the *Custom Action* will be deployed. Execute it again and the *Custom Action* will be removed.

The code contains *Template Literals* so your browser needs to be ES6-compliant.

Comment: Thx daniel.But When I entry this code in my browser console it put me "incorrect character". And I cannot see in which line...

Comment: Which browser are you using? Have you tried another browser? For me the code works in Firefox 60.0.1 (64-bit) and Chrome 66.0.3359.181 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: I am using IE version 11.0.10240.17831. Thx Daniel for your help. I found another way to get it :)